# Ruby on Rails Devise -- Redirect after edit profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

How do I use the Ruby on Rails devise gem to stay on the Edit User page after I edit my information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

First, create a RegistrationsController in the CLI by typing
`rails g controller Registrations`

Then, create a new folder called `my_devise` in your `app/controllers` folder, and move the newly generated `RegistrationsController` into that folder.

Next, open up `RegistrationsController`, and change the contents to

```
class MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected 
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    user_path(resource)
  end
end
```

Now, move the `app/views/devise/registrations` folder to a new folder called `app/views/my_devise/registrations`, but leave the `sessions` and `shared` folders in the `devise` folder.

Then, in the `config/routes.rb` file, change the line `devise_for :users` to `devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "my_devise/registrations"}.`

And that's it! I think I covered it all.

Answer (score -1):

Override the `after_update_path_for(resource)` method. In your application controller:

```
def after_update_path_for(resource)
  user_edit_path(resource)
end
```

Comment: It still redirects to the home page.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you read through the wiki topic [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile) ? There are a few different methods to go about doing this.

Comment: Sorry but without you posting any code, or a link to a github repo that I can check out, I'm not really sure what else can be done.

Comment: That will never work! Devise doc say "The default url to be used after updating a resource. You need to overwrite this method in your own RegistrationsController."

Comment: @FernandoKosh Exactly. Today I've seen at least four answers related to Devise redirections just like this and all they say to put the redirect logic into ApplicationController, not in RegistrationsController if it's about signing up or updating, or ConfirmationsController if it's about confirming an account. I wonder if they just copy/paste the code having no idea whatsoever whether it works or not. I feel sorry for those poor folks trying to make work something that is not supposed to work by design.